# How to hide alert message in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to jQuery and MVC. I have a login scenario that shows `alert` messages when username or password is wrong. I have used `ViewData` for passing messages from controller to view and showing alert message through javascript.

After clicking on the Login button an alert message shows `UserName/Password is wrong. Please try again` with an OK button. Clicking on OK button closes the popup. When I press register new user it navigates me to the register page but when I press back button for login screen the alert message shows again on login screen. Below is the code that I am working.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = _proxy.Get<LoginResult>(string.Format("{0}api/Login/Login?userName={1}&password={2}", ConfigurationUtils.GetValue("ApplicationServiceUri"), model.UserName, model.Password));

        if (result.Success)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["alertMessage"] = result.Message;
            return View();
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

My View script is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {             
    var success = @((TempData["alertMessage"] != null).ToString().ToLower());
    debugger;
    if (success == true) {
        var status = '@TempData["alertMessage"]';
        var wnd = $("#window");
        $(".spn-login-message").text(status);
        if (!wnd.data("kendoWindow")) {
            wnd.kendoWindow({
                modal: true,
                title: "Login",

                close: function () {
                    $(".open-button").show();
                },
                visible: false
            });
        }
        var dialog = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
        dialog.center();
        wnd.data("kendoWindow").open();
        $(this).hide();

        $(".btn-primary").click(function () {
            // call 'close' method on nearest kendoWindow
            $(this).closest("[data-role=window]").kendoWindow("close");
        });
    }
    else{
        $("#btnOK").hide();

    }
});
```

My concern is that how to hide alert message when page refresh or back button is pressed for navigating to login page.
Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the [Post-Redirect-Get pattern described here](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-post-redirect-get-pattern/)

So in your case, you would do this:

```
 if (result.Success)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["alertMessage"] = result.Message;
        RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```

Notice we are redirecting (which will do a get), instead of returning the view. If the user refreshes, then they will be refreshing the get, instead of the post.

Answer (score 0):

I Have done with this situation. Thanks to all :)

Below is my code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

                $(window).on('popstate', function() {
                    var hashLocation = location.hash;
                    var hashSplit = hashLocation.split("#!/");
                    var hashName = hashSplit[1];

                    if (hashName !== '') {
                        var hash = window.location.hash;
                        if (hash === '') {

                        }
                    }
                });

                window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');
            }
```